# Whats the best way to publish a create-react-app to AWS?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, create-react-app, serverless-framework, serverless

I've created a create-react-app locally and I'm using serverless framework for all my local db and apis.

I've just realised I have no idea how I'm going to publish the react app part of my application to AWS.

What is the best way to publish a react app in AWS? Or what are the common ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

no worries, AWS have a solution.
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/
Just one tiny point. This service is free, but the resources deployed whit it are not, so be careful.
Your first job in AWS is to create Cloud Watch alarm when you reach price point. I have alerts when my mountly bill reach 10$, 20$ 100$.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html